# Swift 2.2 - Type Cast fail of generic using base protocol

Tags: swift, generics, casting, protocols, swift2

There is something troubling me.
Here is what I get in Playground:

```
protocol BaseProtocol{}
extension Dictionary : BaseProtocol{}
extension String : BaseProtocol{}

let A : [String:BaseProtocol?] = [
    "A" : "ABC",
    "B" : nil ,
    "C" : "C1"
]

//Direct Cast
let D = A as? [String:String?]  //OK

//'Indirect' Cast
let B : BaseProtocol = A
let C = B as? [String:String?] //Fail -> C == nil

//Two Steps Cast
let E = B as? [String:BaseProtocol?]
let F = E as? [String:String?] //OK
```

So, here is my question. The value stored in B is a valid [String:String?] value. Why the cast to variable C fails?

Is this the desired behavior for the language? Or its something that is 'under development'?

More specific to my case. Im extending Dictionary and Array, I know that I have a BaseProtocol value (like variable B) and need to cast it to Element (Array) or Value(Dictionary) and append it.
But the cast is failing even if the value actually is valid as show for variable C instantiation.

Any help or insight will be very appreciated.

> edit: The "generic" is this case is the Dictionary used in Playground

Comment: It doesnt seems right to me..